# Change DFS Replication scheduled time?

Tags: windows-server-2008, replication, dfs-r

Is it possible to change the scheduled time for DFS replication between replication partners on Windows Server 2008?

We have a backup that runs hourly and interferes with the replication. I then get the event ID 5002 DFSR until the connection is retried and completed successfully.

I could change the scheduled backup times - but i am curious if I can change the replication schedule..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piece of cake.  Open the DFS Management snap-in and add your replication group to the display if it's not already there.  You can right-click on the group and there should be an option to `Edit Replication Group Schedule...`.  Select that and you should be greeted with a dialog that looks like this:

[image: Edit DFSR Schedule]

You can click on individual cells or click and drag over a group of cells.  Then, change the `Bandwidth usage:` drop down to `No replication`.  Alternatively, you can click the Details button and edit the schedule using that interface as well.

**Edit:** I should also mention that you can set the schedule on a per-connection basis rather than globally for the whole replication group.  When you have the group selected in the DFS Management snap-in, switch to the Connections tab and open the Properties dialog for any of the members.  It should have a Schedule tab that is normally set to the group's schedule.  But you can set it to a custom schedule that will only affect that connection.

Comment: That is what I was looking for - I guess I am not permitted to change the schedule for the Domain System Volume however as it is grayed out.

Comment: Ah yes.  Domain replication is a special case with certain restrictions as you found out.